# Context state changes in useEffect result in an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

**What I'm developing:** library for plotting charts|

**Goal:** when updating props in child Curve component, context in CurveTrack must be updated

**Problem:** when using setAxis in useEffect, following error appears: "Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render"

How to fix the problem?

**Sandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-cdn-2h37cd?file=/src/App.tsx

**Code:**

```
const CurveTrack: FC<CurveTrackProps> = ({ children, className, ...props }) => {
  const [axes, setAxes] = useState<{ [key: string]: Axis }>({});

  const setAxis = useCallback((axis: Axis) => {
    setAxes((oldAxes) => ({ ...oldAxes, [axis.name]: axis }));
  }, []);

  const deleteAxis = (axis: Axis) => {
    const updatedAxes = { ...axes };
    delete updatedAxes[axis.name];
    setAxes(updatedAxes);
  };

  return (
    <CurveTrackContext.Provider value={{ axes, setAxis, deleteAxis }}>
      <VictoryChart width={1500} height={400}>
        {Object.values(axes).map((axis) => (
          <VictoryAxis key={axis.name} domain={axis.domain} style={{ axis: { stroke: axis.color } }} />
        ))}
        {children}
      </VictoryChart>
    </CurveTrackContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

```
const Curve: FC<any> = ({ className, children, ...props }) => {
  const { depth, range: xRange } = useLogView();
  const { setAxis } = useAxes();

  const curve = { ...defaultCurve, ...props };
  const curveData = createChart(depth, curve.data);
  const rangedData = rangeData(curveData, xRange);

  const defaultRange = getRange(rangedData.map((data) => data.y));
  const yRange: Range = { ...defaultRange, ...curve.scope };

  useEffect(() => {
    const domain: ForAxes<DomainTuple> = [yRange.min, yRange.max];
    const axis = { name: curve.name, color: curve.style.color, domain };
    setAxis(axis);
  }, [curve, yRange]);

  return <VictoryLine {...props} data={rangedData} style={{ data: { stroke: curve.style.color } }} />;
};
```

**I've tried:**

1. Added and removed setAxis from the array of dependencies
2. Used useCallback
3. Passed setAxes directly (without wrappers setAxis and deleteAxis)
4. Used prevState in setAxes
5. Split the yRange and curve objects into primitive data variables (name, color, min, max)
6. Used useMemo for context value

Comment: You define `curve` as a plan variable and use it as a dependency in `useEffect`, could be that.

Comment: Can you provide a working sample here - https://codesandbox.io/
Would be much easier for others to investigate.

Comment: @ObydulIslamKhan, https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-cdn-2h37cd?file=/src/App.tsx
Will be grateful for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I managed to solve the issues by doing the following the next changes:

First of all, as mentioned in a comment above is not a good idea to put in the useEffect dependencies simple local defined variables because they are recreated at every render so everytime the hook will be triggered causing an infinite loop. To make the current logic work you could put the props directly in the dependencies, but you should make sure there are at least default values in place in case the props are not passed. Another solution would be to transform the curve and yRange variables in state to not be recreated at every render.

```
const Curve: FC<any> = ({ className, children, ...props }) => {
  const { depth, range: xRange } = useLogView();
  const { setAxis } = useAxes();

  const curve = { ...defaultCurve, ...props };
  const curveData = createChart(depth, curve.data);
  const rangedData = rangeData(curveData, xRange);

  const defaultRange = getRange(rangedData.map((data) => data.y));
  const yRange: Range = { ...defaultRange, ...curve.scope };

  useEffect(() => {
    const domain: ForAxes<DomainTuple> = [yRange.min, yRange.max];
    const axis = { name: props.name, color: props.style.color, domain };
    setAxis(axis);
  }, [props.name, props.style.color]);

  return <VictoryLine {...props} data={rangedData} style={{ data: { stroke: curve.style.color } }} />;
};
```

Also in the sandbox you provided I had to give each Curve a name prop because by default you use the defaultCurve constant for both of them and the name provided to the Curves its later used in rendering key for VictoyAxis components in CurveTrack file, and having two components with the same key will cause issues.

```
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <div className="page">
          <LogView
            depth={depth}
            orientation="horizontal"
            grid={{
              main: { style: { color: "red" }, interval: 100 },
              secondary: { style: { color: "red" }, lines: 1 }
            }}
          >
            <CurveTrack>
              <Curve data={ropAvg} name="test1" style={{ color: "red" }} />
              <Curve data={actecdx} name="test2" style={{ color: "green" }} />
            </CurveTrack>
          </LogView>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added "name" prop to every "Curve" and error is gone
[image]